# IIS website not prompting for authentication, and page is blank

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, iis

My SharePoint site has suddenly stopped working. It is not prompting for login. The page simply stops at blank.

I tried creating a new website, and it is working fine. So, it seems there is something wrong in IIS site.

Any suggestion?

**IIS Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: I trust that you have checked that all site in IIS are "Started" and tried an IISRESET?

Comment: added a screenshot of the IIS. only the 'Default Web Site' is stopped. It is because the 'SharePoint - 80' site uses the same port 80. And only one of them can be started at a time. Although it seems the default web site is not relevant. My SharePoint web application is hosted under SharePoint - 80 web site

Comment: so are you sure it's not your default website showing up?

Comment: When I stop 'SharePoint - 80' and start 'Default Web Site', I can visit default web site. In reverse, If I start 'SharePoint - 80' and stop 'Default Web Site', the SharePoint site does not open.